# VMware esxi and windows server 2008 R2 DC

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esx

We are going to install vmware esxi 5.1 on one HP Proliant DL380p G8 server with 4x300GB HDD and make some of our service through that server. we have very small business and only 32 clients. so I want to install Windows Domain Controller on that vmware esxi and the other  windows server machine for antivirus and one windows machine for Bandwith monitoring for client.

but I am a little bit scared about this solution. I am scared about the performance and Windows Server 2008 R2 DC problem?

I want to know that can I install windows Server 2008 r2 DC? Which RAID configuration for local disk? I created RAID 5.

Comment: I'm sorry, but to me it's really unclear what you're asking. 2008 R2 will run fine on ESXi - which bit are you worried about. You should avoid RAID5, though, and having a single DC is not good either because you'll lose your domain if it breaks. Obviously you have a hardware SPOF, but at least that's just an availability issue.

Comment: What's to be scared of?  This is pretty much textbook.

Comment: thank you, which raid do you prefer? and why? and we are every small business and we only have 32 client. the problem is that we dont have large budget to buy SAN or 8x1TBx15K SAS Drive

Comment: @Falcon, scared about the performance. I want to build entire business services through one server and as Dan said, I have SPOF. should I install DC on another PC (not server)?

Comment: You should always have either a second DC, or a frequently-tested known-good restoration procedure from offsite backups. Better to have both, really.

Comment: Why install ESXi 5.1 ? Use 6.5 or later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution is fine. Although you did not specify how much physical RAM would be installed in this server, I'd recommend 16GB or more. A single CPU is okay. Two is better if you plan on virtualizing additional systems.

If you can afford the space, using RAID 1+0 instead of RAID 5 would be my recommendation. Please make sure you have a battery-backed or flash-backed write cache module for this HP Smart Array RAID controller.

In terms of domain controllers, they do not require heavy resources, even when virtualized. I typically use one vCPU and 4GB of RAM for a domain controller.

Comment: +1 for 1 vcPU and 4GB. Exactly what I spec.

Comment: Yes, I have 16GB RAM and I ordered the server controller with 2GB FBWC. exactly I want to know the practical solution. so you did this before and how many client do you have? do you have any problem? any tips?

Comment: Everything Ewwhite has said is really common and trouble free - so long as you know enough about ESXi and Server 2008 and follow the documentation you'll be fine.